# Is it possible to write macros into the excel using NPOI

Tags: c#, excel, openoffice.org, npoi

I am creating an excel using NPOI. In this I want to call an exe(notepad++) when the user clicks a cell. As far as I know this behavior can be achieved only through macros. So is there any possibility that I can write macro into the excel? Or is there any other way to achieve this?. Excel is not an option for me.

Comment: sorry, but the [Manual](https://poi.apache.org/components/spreadsheet/limitations.html) says no. except preparing one master-file with macro and editing that. (i know NPOI is a port of Apache POI and not _exactly_ the same, but i seriously doubt they added that feature without it being backportet to the original)

Comment: I don't know npoi, but maybe you can work with an excel template? In the template you can create your macro behaviour. Or just create an empty excel file with the macros and after inserting data save the file under a new name.